# Telerik RadGrid Virtual Item Count Alignment

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a telerik radgrid, its VirtualItemCount is aligned to the right. I would like to align it to the left. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what are you trying to align? the Grid or the content? what have you tried? googled that?

Comment: I try to align the VirtualItemCount (the number of rows) inside the grid to the left. It should be easily solvable, I just don't know how can I do that. I've checked the attributes of the RadGrid, I've searched for the answer at the telerik site and I've also googled. This is a straight-forward question which should be easily solvable, but not seeing anything useful I didn't make any tries.

Comment: Do you mean the bit at the bottom which shows the paging etc?

Comment: I mean the "Item 1 to 100 of 3950" part. Also, the bit referred by you is not necessarily in the bottom, its location depends on the skin of telerik:RadGrid or on the markup if it overwrites it, but good question comment (+1), I believe it helped to clarify my question.

Comment: In that case, have you seen this demo? http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/pagertemplate/defaultcs.aspx - you can template out that part of the grid and output however you want.

Comment: Thanks, this might work, but I think it's better to align the virtual item count by jquery or css than this solution, because I would like to use my general skins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a simple solution to my problem, so I implemented a hack in jQuery:

```
            $(".rgInfoPart").each(function(){
                var obj = $($(this).parent().find(".rgPagerButton")[1]);
                $(this).css("left", (obj.position().left + obj.width() + 10) + "px");
                $(this).css("position", "absolute");
            });
```